# Asp.Net Core 2.1 Request exlusing client side cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a problem where cookies set in the website using javascript are not being passed to controllers in the Request.  Any cookies set in C# are present.

In my Startup.cs I have set the following:

ConfigureServices:

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;// must be false otherwise only essential cookies will be allowed
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;              
});
```

Configure:

```
app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions
{
    HttpOnly = HttpOnlyPolicy.None
});
```

when inspecting the cookies in the browser the one I want - "ClientTimeZone" is present as can be seen in this image:

[image]

but in the controller when looking at the Request that cookie is not present:

[image]

The JavaScript code I use to store cookies are as follows:

```
setCookie: function (name, value, days)
    {
        var expires = "";
        if (days)
        {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
        }
        document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "") + expires + ";";
    },
```

I have also tried adding `path=/` but no luck.

Any suggestions as to why the cookie does not persist to the server?

Thanks,

Comment: I think it's better to use `F12` to inspect what the actual request is sent to your server. We have no idea on how you invoke your js code to set cookie.  Also, we don't know whether you're sending the request with credentials/cookies or not.

Comment: @itminus thanks. Once I'm back at a computer I'll verify. It is being sent with other cookies but no others that were specified in JavaScript. If I add that same cookie in C# it remains and round-trips to client and server.  Ill add a fiddler request file when I get back to work. Cheers

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm running into the same issue on .NET Core 2.2.  HttpOnly = None, Secure = SameAsRequest.  I've verified in browser Dev Tools that the cookie is sent in the Request Headers, it's just not showing up in the Request.Cookies collection.

Comment: Hi @MichaelGagne if I remember right in my case it had to do with the cross origin policy.  In the Startup.cs under the Configure function I had to set: app.UseCors(c=> c.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin());

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to spaces in your cookie value (and in my case, Json).  .NET Core is using [RFC-6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265).
Allowed characters are alphanumerics plus     `~!@#$%^&*()-_+[]{}|`.  Space, comma, semi-colon, backslash, and quotes are not allowed.

The simplest fix is to use Uri encoding/decoding.

Javascript to set cookie value:

```js
document.cookie = 'ClientTimeZone=' + encodeURIComponent("New Zealand Time") + ';path=/';
```

C# to read it:

```
var timeZone = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(Request.Cookies["ClientTimeZone"]);
```

The source of the issue is when parsing header values into cookies:

```
Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaderParser
{
    protected virtual bool TryParseValues(IList<string> values, bool strict, out IList<T> parsedValues)
}
```

Eventually hits the following method, which exits as soon as it hits a disallowed character:

```
Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.CookieHeaderValue
{
    internal static StringSegment GetCookieValue(StringSegment input, ref int offset)
}
```

Essentially, even though the cookie is sent in the request header, any cookie that doesn't parse correctly is silently ignored and never included in the IRequestCookieCollection Request.Cookies.